# How to add a badge value to an android tabview?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I have a Nativescript Angular app with a tabview. I want to place a badge on tab items where action is needed. On iOS I succeeded to do this, however on android I didn't. I found this thread: https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/nativescript-android-add-badge-on-tabview-tabs/4768 but that didn't help me. Maybe that doesn't work on Nativescript 5.x anymore...

I'm using this code to alter my tabview. Everything is working except the android setBadge part.

```
import { TabView } from "tns-core-modules/ui/tab-view/tab-view";
import { isAndroid, isIOS } from "tns-core-modules/platform/platform";

export class TabViewService {

    private TabView: TabView;

    private androidInitialHeight;

    setTabView(tabview: TabView) {
        this.TabView = tabview;
        console.log("TABVIEW SET");

        if (isAndroid) {
            const tabLayout = this.TabView.nativeViewProtected.tabLayout;
            this.androidInitialHeight = tabLayout.getLayoutParams().height;
        }
    }

    getTabView() {
        return this.TabView;
    }

    hideTabView() {
        console.log("HIDING TABVIEW");
        if (isIOS) {
            this.TabView.viewController.tabBar.hidden = true;
        }
        if (isAndroid) {
            const tabLayout = this.TabView.nativeViewProtected.tabLayout;
            tabLayout.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
            tabLayout.requestLayout();
        }
    }

    showTabView() {
        console.log("SHOWING TABVIEW");
        if (isIOS) {
            this.TabView.viewController.tabBar.hidden = false;
        }
        if (isAndroid) {
            const tabLayout = this.TabView.nativeViewProtected.tabLayout;
            tabLayout.getLayoutParams().height = this.androidInitialHeight;
            tabLayout.requestLayout();
        }
    }

    setBadgeValue(tabIndex: number, value: number) {
        value = value === 0 ? null : value;
        console.log("SETTING BADGE VALUE OF INDEX: " + tabIndex);
        if (isIOS) {
            const tabItem = this.TabView.ios.tabBar.items[tabIndex];
            tabItem.badgeValue = value.toString();
        }

        if (isAndroid) {

        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Comment: I had posted the original [Playground sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=i44ty0&v=3), I don't see any issues with it, just runs fine on 5.x.

Comment: You're right, it does work. However it creates some errors that are now preventing me from reinstalling my node_modules folder because of a post install script. Error: ../../src/app/shared/services/tabview.service.ts:61:26 - error TS2339: Property '_badges' does not exist on type 'TabView'.

61             this.TabView._badges = {};

Comment: That is a simple Typescript error, just cast the variable to any.